# CRON no longer working on Linux Mint 18.2

Tags: shell-script, linux-mint, cron

I've been having issues with CRON lately and I am unable any longer to make it work as it used to up to few days ago.
I've read many advices but so far no nothing works.

The easiest example is this: open amule application at a certain hour of the day:

```
crontab -l
```

:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/home/giuseppe
02 11 * * * /home/giuseppe/amulesched.sh
```

This is the script `amulesched.sh` which runs without any problem in the CLI:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/amule
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed DISPLAY Was missing, that was it! It looks like I messed up the script versions! really appreciated

Comment: Also, the crontab does not  need (should not have) a `#!`-line. It's not a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amule is a program with a GUI. If started from cron, does it have access to an X windows server? In your script, you don't set DISPLAY.